# Android App is not connecting to Firebase database in realtime

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot see what I'm missing. All I want is to enter text from 2 edittext boxes and then click a save button to update to the database. Please see below for more information and thank you very much for any help. The database is very simple, it is called just "users", if there's any other information I can provide please let me know. Thank you.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:hint="enter your first name"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="enter your last name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputFirstName" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/inputLastName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.firedemo
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class user(
    var firstname: String,
    var lastname: String
)

private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
private var userId: String = ""

//EditText
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var firstNameEt: EditText
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var lastNameEt: EditText

//Button
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var saveButton: Button


 abstract class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), Parcelable {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        dbReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users")

firstNameEt = findViewById(R.id.inputFirstName)
        lastNameEt = findViewById(R.id.inputLastName)


        userId = dbReference.push().key.toString()

        saveButton.setOnClickListener{
            val firstname: String = firstNameEt.text.toString()
            val lastname: String = lastNameEt.text.toString()
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)){
                createUser(firstname, lastname)
            } else{
                null
            }

        }

    }

    private fun createUser(firstname: String, lastname: String){

    // Write a message to the database

        val user = user(firstname, lastname)
        dbReference.child(userId).setValue(user)
    }


    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firedemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Firedemo">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firedemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

}
```

Comment: What exactly in all these lines of code doesn't work the way you expect? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without reading data from any UI elements? For example with hardcoded values in `createUser(firstname, lastname)`? That would mean all the XML is not needed, and you can remove it from your question. Focussing the question like that, is a great way to improve the chance that someone can help.

Comment: If the `dbReference.child(userId).setValue(user)` is not writing to the database, you'll want to add a completion listener for its completion to see if there are any errors. See here for an example of how to do that: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75 If you don't solve it with that, show the updated code and its output in your question.